# how do parse JSON in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

This is my json string
    `"[{"/stab/cg/{4CD742B1-C1CA-4708-BE78-0FCA2EB01A86}/TOPS_00":[{"key":"C0.A8.01.06","value":"31"},{"key":"C0.A8.50.01","value":"25"},{"key":"C0.A8.50.81","value":"22"},{"key":"E0.00.00.FC","value":"19"},{"key":"C0.A8.01.FF","value":"18"},{"key":"C0.A8.50.FF","value":"18"},{"key":"4A.7D.EC.5F","value":"11"},{"key":"4A.7D.EC.4E","value":"11"},{"key":"SYS:GROUP_TOTALS","value":"158"}]}]"`

after **eval('('+ evt.data + ')')**, i need to get  like this

> ["/stab/cg/{4CD742B1-C1CA-4708-BE78-0FCA2EB01A86}/TOPS_00",[{"key":"C0.A8.01.06","value":"31"},{"key":"C0.A8.50.01","value":"25"},{"key":"C0.A8.50.81","value":"22"},{"key":"E0.00.00.FC","value":"19"},{"key":"C0.A8.01.FF","value":"18"},{"key":"C0.A8.50.FF","value":"18"},{"key":"4A.7D.EC.5F","value":"11"},{"key":"4A.7D.EC.4E","value":"11"},{"key":"SYS:GROUP_TOTALS","value":"158"}]]

How can i get this  using javascript?

Comment: `document.write(jsonString)`? Your output is the same as your input!

Answer (score 1):

If you can utilize jQuery you can use the `$.parseJSON()` method. Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

For prototype use the `.evalJSON()` method. Documentation [here](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/evalJSON)

Comment: Try using `evt.data.evalJSON()`

[Reference](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/json)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `eval` for this. A collection of libraries for parsing JSON is listed near the end of [the JSON homepage](http://json.org/), there are a couple for JavaScript including [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) which is the usual choice.

Manipulating the data structure has nothing to do with parsing JSON though. If you really want to transform it like then then you'd want something like (untested):

```
var newObj = [];
for (keys) in myObj) {
    newObj.push([key].concat(myObj[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse has a native implementation in most modern browsers and you can shim it using the implementation on the JSON homepage that Quentin indicated.